# Find the primary key on a table in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to write a stored procedure to get all the dependencies on a table. Here is the code which I tried and I dont really get any output from it.

Tere are two blocks of cod. The first one is to get the FK and PK for this table. The second block gets the FK references from other tables.

I have taken table name and schema names as input and all the other variables as out. i was trying to make this code dynamic.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: I was trying to find out where the issue was but could find. it doesnt give me any error nor the output when i execute this code

Comment: What output are you expecting? How did you call it, and how did you disolay the out parameters?

Comment: I want to see the dependencies(primarykey,foreignkey) on a particular table which we provide as input(schema name and table name). I try to execute the code but nothing gets displayed

Comment: Oracle provides a data dictionary called ALL_CONS_COLUMNS to check what all columns of a table has which all constraints. Why do't you use that rather than writing a pl sql block

Comment: You presented a solution and are asking us why it doesn't work. You will get much better help if you spend some time expressing the problem as clearly as you can. Something like:  "I am looking to get a table name from the user, and to return the following information, in exactly the following format... for example (use an example from a standard schema here, like HR or SCOTT)" Explain exactly what logic must be followed. Showing what you have tried is always important, but stating the problem first is even more important.

Comment: You probably need to return a cursor rather than a bunch of variables, because tables can have more than one constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use out variable in where clause:

```
and rowner is not null
and rconstraintname is not null
and rconstraintname in (select constraint_name from all_constraints) ;
```

It should be **r_constraint_name** and **r_owner**
In the second query add constraint_name in subquery:

```
and table_name = tablename
and constraint_name = ac.r_constraint_name)
```

And hear @WilliamRobertson ;)